# simple CSS Grid tainted by Vertical scrollbar

Tags: html, angular, css, css-grid

my angular application which is laid out with CSS Grid has a vertical scrollbar on what looks like the body.  I have put a zero margin on the body and my grid-template-rows add up to 100.  I don't know what other factors could possibly be causing this.  Here is my stackblitz [sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gridpositioning-001).

Here is the code that may be problematic:

```
body{
    margin:0px !important;
}

#page {
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    grid-template-areas: "head head"
                         "nav  main"
                         "nav  foot";
    grid-template-rows: 10vh 90vh;
    grid-template-columns: 250px 1fr;
  }
```

Thank you for your insights!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your style in `app.component.css` is not applied because, angular will apply the style you specified only to that particular component. So, what ever style you have given in `app.component.css` it will be applied only to `app.component.html`. This is to make sure that, the css you applied in one component doesnt affect the styling of someother component.

Since, `<body>` is part of `index.html`, you to need to give

```
body{
    margin:0px;
}
```

in `styles.css`. You can think it of as global style.

Edit: In your `index.html` even though `body` tag is not present, angular will add these `html`, `head` and `body` tags, since it has to insert the compiled scripts in the index page.

Answer (score 2):

You need:

`html, body {
   margin: 0;
}`

Answer (score 1):

body tag have some default margin.

Either remove the margins by adding margin:0 on body tag.

Or update #page style, which takes into account the default margin on body tag

```
grid-template-rows: calc(10vh - 8px) calc(90vh - 8px);
```